# Extend R memory storage

Tags: r, memory, storage

As most advices on this topic were related for Windows machines and 3GB RAM, I decided to ask in the situation of Unix.

Machine description: I have a 64-bit with 7.8 RAM, CPU@3.4 GHzx8 , and more than 400 GB of memory space available. I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Problem: I have a matrix with 26000 columns and 600 rows.  I need to obtain a correlation matrix with respect to the columns. This will of course produce a 26kx26k matrix which doing the simple maths (226k x 26k x 8/1024 x 1024 x 1024) gives more than 5GB. I need to obtain three correlation matrices like this. Then I based on each correlation matrix, I need to obtain three further matrices which will give me a total of 9 matrices or a big one -  (3 x 26k) x (3 x 26k). 
As you see, I have plenty of RAM and storage, but I need to extend the overall memory of R to be able to store all these matrices.

I tried `R --min-vsize=10M --max-vsize=100M --min-nsize=500k --max-nsize=1M` as suggested on the R website, but apparently

```
WARNING: option '--max-vsize=100M' no longer supported
WARNING: option '--max-nsize=1M' no longer supported
```

I had other ideas of computing smaller sub-correlation matrices, etc. but I will eventually need to have all the matrices in R as I need to obtain further analysis on the data.

Any ideas of how to extend the memory so that I can compute all these matrices?